# gnuplot - use a value that repeats all over the graph (like a baseline)

Tags: gnuplot

I was not able to find a solution to this; except using the nasty trick to make another column with the same value over and over again.

I am trying to add a line that would show the daily target of the data that is displayed. I have a simple script that takes the data file, calculate the target and save it on the data file.

Now I would like to have the target displayed on top of the graph, so I can see which values goes beyond and which below the target number.

The only way to do so was to copy and paste the value for each of the value that I display, on a different column, which is ugly to many levels.

Is there a way to tell gnuplot to use a value as constant all over the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course, this is the easiest function

```
f(x)=const
plot f(x)
```

or just

```
plot const
```

note that you can use gnuplot system command to fill the constant(s)
it you tune your script to produce something like "const=123.456; const2=987.654"
then you can load it in gnuplot via pipe:

```
load "< myscript.sh my_args"
```

or alternatively with the system command (if the script just return one value):

```
const=system("myscript.sh my_args")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Why the docs do not explain these things clearly is beyond me

Comment: @newbiez Feel free to improve the documentation :)

Comment: one more thing, since you want to highlight the diffenrence between your curve and a value, look at filledcurves: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/fillcrvs.html
you will probably want to try "plot 'mydata.dat'  with filledcurve y1=const"